# Cambiar el aspecto del cuadro de texto en PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Cómo podría cambiar el aspecto del cuadro de texto en PyCharm? Gracias de antemano por sus valiosas respuestas!!!

[image: Cuadro de texto de ayuda]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ok, lo que quise decir es que cuando estás creando alguna función comando o cualquier otra acción, cuando el cursor queda por ejemplo en la imagen adjuntada entre los paréntesis, sale automáticamente un cuadro de texto descriptivo de lo que debes de ir colocando dentro de ese paréntesis, lo que quisiera saber como cambio el aspecto de ese cuadro de texto(Fondo, Color de los comandos, etc.) Lo he visto en otros tutoriales que usan PyCharm y son de colores distintos a los que vienen por defecto... Gracias nuevamente por tú valiosa ayuda al respecto.